# Alpine.js show/hide image for a image selector

Tags: alpine.js

Here I have an image selector. When an image link is clicked in the second <\li> it will show in the first <\li>. This works fine.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is also hide the {{--Place holder Image--}} when the image link is clicked in the second <\li>.

```
<div x-data="{ image: '' }" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{--Placeholder Image --}}
            <img x-show="image = true" src="/img/image1">

            @foreach($images as $image)
                 <img x-show="image === '{{ $image->id }}'" src="{{ $image->path }}">
            @endforeach
         </li>

         @foreach($image as $image)
         </li>
             <a href="#" @click.prevent="image = '{{ $image->id }}'">
                 <img src="{{ $image->path }}">
            </a>
         </li>
         @endforeach
     </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.
Just needed to change `'x-show="image = true"'` to `x-show="image === ''"` in the placeholder image tag.